# Подскажите как правильно удалить дочерний элемент javascript/insertAdjacentHTML/removeChild

Tags: javascript, html

Суть в том, что при нажатии на кнопку появляется элемент посредством insertAdjacentHTML, при повторном нажатии элемент удаляется. На данный момент элемент добавляется и удаляется если на кнопки нажимать в последовательном порядке. Т.е. один раз нажал - список появился, второй раз нажал - список исчез, но если нажать на один элемент, потом на второй, потом снова на первый - элемент не удаляется, а если нажать на второй, то удалится

Код:

```
<button class="select" value="1" onclick="selectedList('${adress}')">

function selectedList(adress) {
if(event.currentTarget.value == 1){
    alert('1')
    event.currentTarget.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="modalWr"><li>${adress}</li><li>${adress}</li></div>`)
    event.currentTarget.value = 0
}
else{
    alert('0')
    event.currentTarget.value = 1
    event.currentTarget.parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector('.modalWr'))
    event.remove()
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получается при нажатии, неважно в какой последовательности добавлялись элементы скрываются только самые верхние по очереди

Comment: а нафига селекторы с классами? если надо конкретный - используйте id и селектор по id соответственно

Comment: Дак там id все равно одинаковый будет у всех элементов, т.к. идет динамическое добавление элемента. (Если не прав - поправьте)

Comment: `onclick="selectedList('${adress}')"` - у вас тут синтаксическая ошибка, нужно писать вот так: `onclick="selectedList(\`${adress}\`)"`.

Comment: Нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом, в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M и вставьте ваш минимальный воспроихводимый код по нужным секциям. Перел вставкой нажмите на "Привести в порядок", а потом на "Запустить" и убедитесь что нет всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких ошибок в консоли